# VBA, syntax, group range of cells together for common variable

Tags: excel, vba

Im working on a little script (below). The script iterates through rows on a data set and places either a 1 or 0 in a cell based on some contingencies of 2 select case statements. It works perfect, but I want to know if there's a way to group the range of cells together that are getting a 0 placed within them.

```
Sub compVal()

Dim WB As Workbook  'an object of type workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet ' objects of type worksheet

Set WB = ActiveWorkbook ' reference WB to the current Workbook
Set WS1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Reference to Sheet 1 of the current workbook

'loop through sheet1's rows
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To WS1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

   Select Case WS1.Cells(i, 1).Value 'first cell from row i

      Case "Target"

         Select Case WS1.Cells(i, 2).Value

            Case 1

               WS1.Cells(i, 3).Value = 1
               WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = 0
               WS1.Cells(i, 5).Value = 0
               WS1.Cells(i, 6).Value = 0

            Case 2

               WS1.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0
               WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = 0
               WS1.Cells(i, 5).Value = 1
               WS1.Cells(i, 6).Value = 0

         End Select

      Case "NonTarget"

         Select Case WS1.Cells(i, 2).Value

            Case 1

               WS1.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0
               WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = 1
               WS1.Cells(i, 5).Value = 0
               WS1.Cells(i, 6).Value = 0

            Case 2

               WS1.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0
               WS1.Cells(i, 4).Value = 0
               WS1.Cells(i, 5).Value = 0
               WS1.Cells(i, 6).Value = 1
         End Select

      End Select
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: What do you mean by group them together?

Comment: You can consolidate your code quite a bit by using (eg) `WS1.Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(1, 0, 0, 0)`  to assign your cell values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great example of code re-use:

```
Sub compVal()

Dim WB As Workbook  'an object of type workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet ' objects of type worksheet

Set WB = ActiveWorkbook ' reference WB to the current Workbook
Set WS1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Reference to Sheet 1 of the current workbook

'loop through sheet1's rows
Dim i As Long ' USE LONG FOR CELL REFERENCES, THERE ARE A LOT OF ROWS POSSIBLE : )

For i = 2 To WS1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

   Select Case WS1.Cells(i, 1).Value 'first cell from row i

      Case "Target"

         Select Case WS1.Cells(i, 2).Value

            Case 1

               AddColumns WS1, i, 1, 0, 0, 0

            Case 2

               AddColumns WS1, i, 0, 0, 1, 0

         End Select

      Case "NonTarget"

         Select Case WS1.Cells(i, 2).Value

            Case 1

               AddColumns WS1, i, 0, 1, 0, 0

            Case 2

               AddColumns WS1, i, 0, 0, 0, 1

         End Select

      End Select
Next i
End Sub

Sub AddColumns(WS As Worksheet, i As Long, c As Variant, d As Variant, e As Variant, f As Variant)
    WS.Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(c, d, e, f)

End Sub
```

There are other efficiencies that could be introduced, such as replacing the four arguments c,d,e and f with a single integer where

```
0  = 0,0,0,0
1  = 1,0,0,0
2  = 0,1,0,0
...
15 = 1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Note that you should be using `Dim i As Long` as Int is not adequate if you have lots of rows

Comment: Great, thank you all for the heads up. I'm still pretty green when it comes to scripting so any tidbits help quite a bit. Thank you all again